# How to align multiple table columns vertically

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have multiple tables with the following structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">year</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">semester</td>
        <td colspan="2">semester</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>course type</td>
        <td>course</td>
        <td>course type</td>
        <td>course</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Because the contents of the tables are not the same, cells don't line up vertically, and I get an ugly look.

```css
/* set-up */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
    background: gainsboro;
}
#container {
    width: 752px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
table:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
tr.thead td, td.thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
}
tr.thead2 td, td.thead2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">Third-year (2015-2016)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dil Becerilerinin Öğretimi I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Çocuklara Yabancı Dil Öğretimi I</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">Second-year (2014-2015)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dilbilim I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dilbilim II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dil Edinimi</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İngilizce Öğretiminde Yaklaşımlar I</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">First-year (2013-2014)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Bağlamsal Dilbilgisi I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Bağlamsal Dilbilgisi II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İleri Okuma ve Yazma I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İleri Okuma ve Yazma II</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

If I give cells a fixed width, I get the desired [result (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/o3xoryac/).

```
/* course-type cells */
tr:nth-child(n+2) td:nth-child(odd) {
    width: 50px;
}
/* course cells */
tr:nth-child(n+2) td:nth-child(even) {
    width: 306px;
}
```

But that works only if I enter the widths manually. I want the course-type cells to be `50px`, and course cells to take the remaining space. `306px` isn't a fixed value. If the width of the container changes, `306px` won't work because table's width is set to `100%`. So I thought about using `calc` function:

```
/* course cells */
tr:nth-child(n+2) td:nth-child(even) {
    /* (container-width(752) - (course-type-cell*2) - (container-padding*2)) / 2 */
    width: calc((100% - (50px * 2) - (20px * 2)) / 2); /* 306px */
}
```

but it doesn't work. I don't think `calc` is getting the correct `100%` value, or not getting it at all. I wanted to make sure that all parent elements inherit the container's width, so that `calc` would work

```
table, tbody, tr {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't [work](http://jsfiddle.net/o3xoryac/1/). Is using fixed width my only option, or is there a way to make `calc` work?

Comment: You should simply put all of them in the same table, and use `colspan` for individual year headers.

Comment: Done. This seems an easier way to do it. Although, there is still the `calc` issue.

Comment: I agree, this really does seem the easiest way to do it, after 15 years of dealing with this issue. I have heard not to use colspan because that kind of stuff should be in css... but there isn't a way to do colspan with css... or is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using separate tables, you can use one table with invisible spacer rows to make each section look like a separate table. That way it will behave as one table when the browser calculates the layout, but the final result will look like three tables.

The general idea is that you have it all in one table, and between each section you will a spacer row that looks like this:

```
<tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

The spacer row has the following CSS style to make it invisible:

```
tr.spacer td {
    border: none;
}
```

---

Here is a screenshot of the final result:

[image: Final result]

And here is a **Live Demo** of the code in action:

```css
/* set-up */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
    background: gainsboro;
}
#container {
    width: 752px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
table:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
tr.thead td, td.thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
}
tr.thead2 td, td.thead2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    padding: 4px;
}

tr.spacer td {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">Third-year (2015-2016)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dil Becerilerinin Öğretimi I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Çocuklara Yabancı Dil Öğretimi I</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">Second-year (2014-2015)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dilbilim I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dilbilim II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Dil Edinimi</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İngilizce Öğretiminde Yaklaşımlar I</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="thead">
            <td colspan="4">First-year (2013-2014)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thead2">
            <td colspan="2">Autumn</td>
            <td colspan="2">Spring</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Bağlamsal Dilbilgisi I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Bağlamsal Dilbilgisi II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İleri Okuma ve Yazma I</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>İleri Okuma ve Yazma II</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/bmyhqevw/

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/