# How can I align columns across multiple tables?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to align the `<td>` correctly, except that the first 2 `<td`> of the table are not positioned perfectly.
Do you know how I could rectify this, please?

A big thank you

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dToN2.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="pt-3 container">
         <div class="card" style="width: 60%">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                     <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
                        <tbody>
                           <ng-container *ngFor="let element of dta.PTF_DTA">
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Année Exercice</th>
                                 <td>2022</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Pays formulaire DTA</th>
                                 <td>4</td>
                              </tr>
                           </ng-container>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
                        <tbody>
                           <ng-container *ngFor="let element of dta.PTF_DTA">
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Registre national</th>
                                 <td>123</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Nom</th>
                                 <td>PERSONNE PHYSIQUE 47818</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Prénom</th>
                                 <td>PERSONNE PHYSIQUE 47818</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Lieu de Naissance</th>
                                 <td>XXXXXXXXX</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Date de Naissance</th>
                                 <td>01/01/0001</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Pays de la residence fiscale</th>
                                 <td>BEL</td>
                              </tr>
                           </ng-container>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a matter of two cells being "incorrect". Tables are separate structures and their interior sizing is calculated independently. You'll have to apply manual sizing to get columns to align.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align multiple table columns vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555199/how-to-align-multiple-table-columns-vertically)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to align columns in multiple tables in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332955/is-there-a-way-to-align-columns-in-multiple-tables-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have separated the content into two separate tables, but are displaying them as though they were a single, continuous table.  If this is all tabular data that logically belongs together, just combine it into a single table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="pt-3 container">
         <div class="card" style="width: 60%">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                     <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
                        <tbody>
                           <ng-container *ngFor="let element of dta.PTF_DTA">
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Année Exercice</th>
                                 <td>2022</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Pays formulaire DTA</th>
                                 <td>4</td>
                              </tr>
                           </ng-container>
                           <ng-container *ngFor="let element of dta.PTF_DTA">
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Registre national</th>
                                 <td>123</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Nom</th>
                                 <td>PERSONNE PHYSIQUE 47818</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Prénom</th>
                                 <td>PERSONNE PHYSIQUE 47818</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Lieu de Naissance</th>
                                 <td>XXXXXXXXX</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Date de Naissance</th>
                                 <td>01/01/0001</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Pays de la residence fiscale</th>
                                 <td>BEL</td>
                              </tr>
                           </ng-container>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, looking at the data, you might be better served semantically with something like a [description list `<dl>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) with [description term `<dt>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt) and [description detail `<dd>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd) pairs for the left and right sides of each "table row".